# How to pass parameters to Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010? Looks like they are ignored

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

This was working correctly in Visual Studio 2008, but since I have switch to Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010, my passed parameters are ignored.

They display in the report, just ignored when it comes to the selection formula! Here is my code for creating the report and passing the parameters.

```
 private void Prepare()
    {
        var reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

        string reportPath = string.Format(
            "{0}\\{1}",
            Globals.FormPath,
            this.FormTemplate.Filename);

        reportDocument.Load(reportPath);

        ParameterDiscreteValue parameter;

        foreach (var control in this.FormTemplateFieldControls)
        {
            switch (control.FormTemplateField.DataType)
            {
                case FormFieldDataType.Date:
                    this.AddParameterForDateTime(
                        reportDocument,
                        control.FormTemplateField.Name,
                        (DateTime)control.EditValue);
                    break;
                case FormFieldDataType.DateTime:
                    this.AddParameterForDateTime(
                        reportDocument,
                        control.FormTemplateField.Name,
                        (DateTime)control.EditValue);
                    break;
                case FormFieldDataType.Time:
                    this.AddParameterForDateTime(
                        reportDocument,
                        control.FormTemplateField.Name,
                        (DateTime)control.EditValue);
                    break;
                case FormFieldDataType.Guid:
                    this.AddParameterForGuid(
                        reportDocument,
                        control.FormTemplateField.Name,
                        (Guid)control.EditValue);
                    break;
                default:
                    this.AddParameterForString(
                        reportDocument,
                        control.FormTemplateField.Name,
                        control.EditValue.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }

        this.SetConnectionInfo(reportDocument);

        var frm = new FormViewer();

        frm.Report = reportDocument;

        frm.ShowDialog();

        frm.Dispose();

        this.Close();
    }
```

When I run the report from the designer it works just fine. You can see the parameters are being passed as I am displaying them in my report.

[image]

For my reports that run from stored procedures the parameters seem to pass just fine, it's just the ones composed of all tables.

For what it's worth, here is my selection formula:

```
 {employee.HireDate} >= {?StartDate} And {employee.HireDate} <= {?EndDate}
```

Comment: Even if I just try letting Crystal Reports prompt for the parameters they don't get passed.

Comment: What's really weird, is if I step through the code, and look at the values of the parameters at run-time, it displays correctly.

Comment: So I switched my report to use a stored procedure and it worked ... but I shouldn't have to do this ... ugh!

Comment: I am having the same problem.
I have a report that accesses a view and the parameter passed in is supposed to identify one record in the view and that is what the report shows.  
From what I can tell, the parameter is being passed in correctly.  I can display it in the report.  
However, the view is not filtering against the parameter, which is what it was doing when I ran this in VS2005.  I confirm this using Profiler.  With VS2005 there is a where clause added to the query, with 2010, there is not.
I have tried changing the parameter name and redoing the record select with no success.
T

Comment: @Neil What we ended up doing was just creating a website using VS 2008 that referenced the old CR assemblies, and just have our Windows/Web app written using VS 2010 send all reports to the website. It's hackish, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved with the latest version of Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "they don't get passed", what DOES get passed? Are they blank?

You might review the parameters themselves, and just for grins, try giving them a different name, something extra unique. There could be something goofy going on with some other report setting or the way the parameters are defined.